# Как можно сделать кастомный Spinner? (фото внутри)

Tags: android, android-spinner

[image: Спиннер]

У меня получается сделать, чтобы выезжающий список оказывался поверх начальной строки, а нужно, чтобы он выезжал ниже ее (как на картинке). Как такое сделать?
И как можно установить справа стрелку, и чтобы она при нажатии на спиннер анимированно повернулась вниз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать кастомный спиннер у вас есть два варианта: использовать библиотеку либо делать самому. Вот есть [либа](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6864) или страница с [либами](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/211). Второй вариант - делать свой спиннер самому подразумевает создание разметки для элемента списка спиннера и стилей для спиннера в целом. Второй вариант более затратный по времени но в итоге вы получаете довольно кастомизируемый вью элемент. Что выбрать зависит от вас.

### UPDATE

1. Делаем разметку (в данном случае моя, но можно сделать какую угодно):

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_weight="17"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textAlignment="gravity"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/number"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
       android:layout_weight="3"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
   ```
2. Дальше делаем адаптер:

   ```
      class SpinnerAdapter(var ctx: Context, var title: List<String>,var count:List<Int>): BaseAdapter() {
   override fun getView(i: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
       val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
       val view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null) as View
       val titles = view1.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
       val counts = view1.findViewById(R.id.number) as TextView
       titles.text = title[i]
       counts.text = count[i].toString()

       return view1
   }

   override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any? {
       return null
   }

   override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
       return 0
   }

   override fun getCount(): Int {
       return title.size
   }
   ```

   }

в данный адаптер шлите ваши данные для заполнения полей.

3. Подключаем все что сделали выше в одну кучу в активности (фрагменте):

   ```
   val recordStatuses = view.findViewById(R.id.recordStatus) as Spinner
   val spinnerAdapter = SpinnerAdapter(context!!, statuses, statusCounts)
   recordStatuses.adapter = spinnerAdapter
   recordStatuses.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
           override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {


           }

           override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

           }
       }
   ```

суть я думаю понятна :)